# Flutter: Take action based on snapshot of Future

Tags: dart, flutter

I've come across a problem while trying out Flutter that I can't figure out. The case I'm thinking of has a `FutureBuilder` widget like below:

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Example Page"),
        ),
        body: new FutureBuilder(
            future: _exampleFuture,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                default:
                  if(snapshot.hasError) {
                    return new Center(child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                  }
                  else {
                    return new Center(child: new Text("Result: ${snapshot.data}"),);
                  }
              }
            }
        )
    );
  }
```

Now let's assume the future is an http call that ends up with a 401 error, indicating that the user is unauthorized.  At this point, I'd like the app to erase any token that's stored and redirect to the login page or just rebuild the app.  But I can't call a method that does that in the build function, and I don't think `didUpdateWidget()` is guaranteed to be called, as the future might return it's value before `build` is called? Maybe I'm approaching this completely wrong, but is there a way to do this in Flutter?

Comment: I have tweaked my code a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for a `statusCode` inside your `Async` method, and use `setState` to erase the value of the token based on the `statusCode` value; otherwise, if the connection is authorized, return your desired data. Now, in your `FutureBuilder` , check if the you snapshot is null to show a `SignIn()` page instead.

For example, your method that handles the http requests might look something like:

```
_Request() async {
    var httpClinet = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClinet.get(
        url, headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer $_currentUserToken"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var myRequest = JSON.decode(response.body);
      var myDesiredData;

      ///TODO: Some data conversions and data extraction
      return myDesiredData;
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _currentUserToken = null;
      });
      return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can have a FutureBuilder like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FutureBuilder(
      future: _request(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot response) {
        response.hasData==false? new SignIn(): new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Future Builder"),),
          body: new Center(
            child: new Text("Build your widgets"),
          ),
        );
      },
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks aziza.  That makes sense to me.  I guess I've been getting the future value in `initState()`, as I've been caching the responses and that seems to eliminate any flickering of the screen if I navigate back to the page and the future is retrieved from cache.  Maybe I need to go back to calling a method in the `FutureBuilder` and rethink the rest of the logic a little bit.

Comment: Glad it helped, and hope you work it out eventually.